# Individually specify nested dict fields in pydantic model

Tags: python, pydantic

Is it possible to specify the individual fields in a dict contained inside a pydantic model? I was not able to find anything but maybe I'm using the wrong keywords. I'm thinking of something like this:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str = 'Jane Doe'
    stats = {
        age: int,
        height: float,
    }
```

---

EDIT: After some feedback I feel I need to clarify a bit some of the conditions of this and give a more complete example. What I'm looking to do is more similar to this:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, NonNegativeInt, NonNegativeFloat
from pydantic.generics import GenericModel

DataT = TypeVar('DataT')

class Trait(GenericModel, Generic[DataT]):
    descript: str
    value: DataT

class CharacterBarbarian(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str = 'Barbarok'
    traits = {
        strength: Trait[NonNegativeInt] = Trait[NonNegativeInt](descript='the force', value=18),
        height: Trait[NonNegativeFloat] = Trait[NonNegativeFloat](descript='tallness', value=1.8),
        weight: Trait[NonNegativeFloat] = Trait[NonNegativeFloat](descript='width', value=92.1),
    }

class CharacterWizard(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str = 'Supremus'
    traits = {
        intelligence: Trait[NonNegativeInt] = Trait[NonNegativeInt](descript='smarts', value=16),
        spells: Trait[NonNegativeInt] = Trait[NonNegativeInt](descript='number of them', value=4),
    }


SavedWizard_dict = { # Read from file for example
    'id': 1234,
    'name': "Gandalf",
    'traits': {
        'intelligence': {'descript': 'smarts', 'value': 20}
        'spells': {'descript': 'number of them', 'value': 100),
    },
}
SavedWizard = CharacterWizard(**SavedWizard_dict)
```

So basically I'm trying to leverage the intrinsic ability of pydantic to serialize/deserialize dict/json to save and initialize my classes. At the same time, these pydantic classes are composed of a list/dict of specific versions of a generic pydantic class, but the selection of these changes from class to class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something similar using nested classes:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class UserStats(BaseModel):
    age: int
    height: float

class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name = 'Jane Doe'
    stats: UserStats
```

Then when you construct any `User` instance you can pass the stats field as a dictionary and it would be converted automatically:

```py
user = User(id=1234, stats={"age": 30, "height": 180.0})
```

The only difference is that the `stats` field of `User` is a class (instance of `UserStats`) so if you want to access fields of it you need to do so using attribute access not using dictionary access:

```py
print(user.age)  # ok!
print(user["age"])  # not ok...
```

If you need ste stats attribute to be a dictionary then you could use `TypedDict` from the `typing_extensions` (python3.7) or `typing` (python3.8+) module:

```py
from typing import TypedDict
from pydantic import BaseModel

class UserStats(TypedDict):
    age: int
    height: float

class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name = 'Jane Doe'
    stats: UserStats

user = User(id=1234, stats={"age": 30, "height": 180.0})
print(user.stats["age"])  # will work!
```

### EDIT:

As mentioned in the comments of this answer the question author did not want to globally define the `UserStats` class to avoid pollution.

This can be solved by defining the class directly inside the `User` class:

```py
class User(BaseModel):
     id: int
     name = "Jane Doe"
     class Stats(TypedDict):
         age: int
         height: float
     stats: Stats
```

This allows for multiple classes like `User` to each define their `stats` without duplicated `Stats` classes in the global namespace.

A more coincise but less friendly to type checkers and language servers would be to use the functional API of `TypedDict`:

```py
 class User(BaseModel):
     id: int
     name = "Jane Doe"
     stats: TypedDict("Stats", age=int, height=float)
```

Comment: Good answer. Just fyi, [`TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) has been included in the (more stable) `typing` module since Python 3.8.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm specifically trying to avoid having to define a separate model for this because I have like 10 of these classes, each with a different "stats" dict, and I would prefer to avoid the duplication of classes.

Comment: @Nordico So... Do you _want_ to define the types in the dictionary or _not_? Because that is _exactly_ what `TypedDict` is for, as Matteo correctly noted. It is even in the official Pydantic [docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#typeddict).

Comment: You can create the `Stats` classes directly inside the scope of the `User` class to avoid pulluting the global namespace... I can include that in my answer

Comment: I was just about to mention the functional API of `TypedDict`. I suggest you also mention that this approach may cause problems with static type checkers (as opposed to the class form of `TypedDict`). EDIT: Ah, you meant something else.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg yeah I meant this... Still the functional API could be an option as well but I think this way is a little friendlier with type checkers and language servers (at least I hope so, haven't tested...)

Comment: Thanks both for the discussion! I ended up using a version of this but with `BaseModel` also for the `stats` instead of `TypedDict` (see edit for reasons why, `TypedDict` didn't instantiate correctly from the dict). I still feel like this is a bit of a smell in the code that needs to be structured in a different way, but for now I'm doing this to restructure another aspect so I'll have to come back to this later (ideas of what could be wrong or sources for the best way to implement something like this are welcome).

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of completeness, you can also make use of the functional API provided by `TypedDict` to write your model like this:

```py
from typing import TypedDict
from pydantic import BaseModel


class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name = 'Jane Doe'
    stats: TypedDict("Stats", {"age": int, "height": float})
```

I can't think of a way to make this more concise. I was not sure at first regarding how this plays with type checkers, but at least PyCharm with the Pydantic plugin seems to have no trouble correctly inferring the types and spitting out warnings, if you try to provide a wrongly typed value in the `stats` dictionary.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! After the exchange in the other reply, I added some clarifying additions to the OP, sorry for the original confusion. I couldn't make use of `TypedDict` because it keeps the `traits` as a dict of strings instead of using the values to initialize the respective pydantic classes.